# SQL without triggers: one query for all the usecases

Tags: sql

Having the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "table2" (
    "field1"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "field2"    BLOB NOT NULL,
    "oldInfo"   INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK("oldInfo" >= 0 AND "oldInfo" <= 1), --0 means False, 1 means True
    FOREIGN KEY("field1") REFERENCES "table1"("field1"),
    PRIMARY KEY("field1","oldInfo")
);
```

I have the following use cases ("oldInfo" field will always be set to zero):

1. First time insert for the pair (field1, oldInfo).
2. Second time insert for the pair (field1, oldInfo). The existing oldInfo field shall be set to one before the insertion of the new row due to the composite key.
3. Third and subsequent insertions for the pair (field1, oldInfo). The row for that field1 where oldInfo is one shall be deleted and then, the row for that field1 where oldInfo is zero shall be modified to have oldInfo set to one, all before the insertion of the new row.

Can I do it with standard SQL into one query without using triggers?

I am using sqlite3 for now, but I would like to have queries that works for every DBMS.

Only one process can access the database at a time, there is no concurrency.

Comment: "I would like to have queries that works for every DBMS" - That was the dream but between the lack of implementation of "standard" features and the number of extensions means that you usually have to abandon this idea or work with a *very* restrictive subset of SQL. E.g. although SQL Server supports the *concept* of Binary Large Objects, it doesn't have a data type called `BLOB`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's what I'm realizing... Thankfully I'm not writing the SQL code at all, I'm using a library where you construct the queries using OOP and, to inspect the SQL code, you have to pass to the SQL printer a DB connection to let the library construct the correct SQL for that engine. I didn't mentioned it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do it on database level you have to do it in trigger or do it through function/procedure.

Othervise you have to do it on application level.

Comment: Thank you! I did it at application level because I think it could be less harmful if someone request me to change the engine tomorrow.

Comment: @Albatros23 It's good decision. You won't regret it.